# Express.js middleware for token forwarding

Tags: node.js, express, token, middleware

I'm in a SSO scenario and my **express** app receive a token auth request,then it needs get data from another server with the same token.

How do I automate this process with a middleware?

**Basic solution**
Each request sets the token

```
var ApiService = require('ApiService.js');
var apiService = new ApiService();

router.route('/')
        .get(function (req, res, next) {

            // getting the token and set to for the api library
            apiService.setToken(req.get('Authorization'));

            apiService.request({
                url: 'route-to-data',
                method: 'get'
            })
                    .then(function (response) {
                        //send data back
                    })
                    .catch(function (response) {})
        })
```

**Express middleware**
Using locale for storing apiservice with the user token

```
var ApiService = require('../apiService/ApiService.js');
var apiService = new ApiService();

var TokenForwarder = function (req, res, next) {
    apiService.setToken(req.get('Authorization'));
    res.locals.apiService = apiService;
    next();
};

module.exports = TokenForwarder;
```

I don't really like this solution, is there a better way?

Comment: What is exactly wrong with the solution? You are using `res.locals` exactly how it was designed to be used, and the middleware provides exactly the functionality you desire.

Comment: I don't like the idea of attaching objects like `apiService` to the response because to me it seems to have a different domain.
I see express provides this way in handling the request response life cycle but I was wondering if there is an alternative way.